# Display sorting options dropdown when using WooCommerce product category shortcode

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, sort

I have a WordPress site, with WooCommerce. The WooCommerce archives pages as shop display a dropdown sorting filter like in this screenshot:

[image]
Now in another page let's say `example.com/foo` On that page I use a WooCommerce shortcode:

```
[product_category per_page="90" columns="3" orderby="" order="ASC" category="foo" prdctfltr="yes" pagination="yes"]
```

But the sorting dropdown is not shown.

What I am doing wrong? How can I display the sorting dropdown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3.2, [Woocommerce shortcodes and their available attributes have changed](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6).

So try the following shortcode instead *(for "foo" product category)*:

```
[product_category limit="90" columns="3" category="foo" paginate="true"]
```

or inside php code:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[product_category limit="90" columns="3" category="foo" paginate="true"]' );
```

Now you will see that the sorting options dropdown appear.

**Note:** `orderby` argument with an empty value **has no effect**. `order` argument is **`ASC` by default**.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you would rather want to get the sorting menu using a shortcode then you can create one for it in your `functions.php`

```
// Creating Shortcode for Product Sorting
add_shortcode('wc_sorting','woocommerce_catalog_ordering');
```

Then simply call the shortcode in your catalog page:-

- In Legacy Editor/Gutenberg: `[wc_sorting]`
- or in your PHP file: `echo do_shortcode('[wc_sorting]');`